# How to pass a value from anadapter class to activity

Tags: android

i want to pass the value of the list(itemvalue) from the adapter class to a activity.Since i am extending the arrayadapter class and not the Activity, i cannot use sharedpreference.I am taking this values into the arraylist(itemname) inside a listener.Here is the code that i have tried.Can anyone help me to  solve this....

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    protected static final String MODE_PRIVATE = null;
    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;


    public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.customlistlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView mText;
        protected CheckBox mCheckbox;

        public string getItemAtPosition(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            final ArrayList<String> itemname = new ArrayList<String>();
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customlistlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_label);
            viewHolder.mCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            Activity activity = new SettingsActivity();
            viewHolder.mCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(activity);
            viewHolder.mCheckbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.mCheckbox
                                    .getTag();  

                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                            **itemname.add(element.getName());**





                        }
                    });
            for (String myValue : itemname) {
                System.out.println(myValue);
            }
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.mCheckbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).mCheckbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.mText.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.mCheckbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CustomArrayAdapter` from where you call this class i mean from mainActivity>?

Comment: Implement CustomArrayAdapter.getList() method to return the encapsulate ArrayList, then call it whenever you want get the ArrayList in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity you are creating CustomArrayAdapter. For example

```
myAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter();
```

then override `setOnListItemClick()` inside the activity.

Comment: i am calling the arrayadapter class as below.ArrayAdapter<Model> settingsadapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this,
   getModel());
 setListAdapter(settingsadapter);

Comment: Inside the activity? If so just   @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) inside your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Create interface
2. Bind interface with adapter while calling constructor class
3. Implement interface in activity
4. Pass data through interface method to activity on some view event in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

create an interface like

```
public interface OnTaskDone{
    void onTaskComplete(Model model);
}
```

add a method like

```
public void setOnTaskDone(OnTaskDone onTaskDone){
    this.onTaskDone = onTaskDone;
}
```

And on check Changed

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.mCheckbox
                                .getTag();  
            onTaskDone.onTaskDone(element);
            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            **itemname.add(element.getName());*

 }
```